# XML Parsing using Retrofit

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, retrofit

I'm trying to make XML Response, but there is an exception.

Exception in onFailure:
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Date' does not have a match in class

[image]

Client

```
public static Retrofit getXMLClient() {

    if (retrofitXML == null) {
        retrofitXML = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofitXML;
}
```

Interface

```
@GET("odds-" + oddsAccessMode + "1"+"?")
Call<PojoOddsResponse> getOddsData(@Query("api_key") String api_key);
```

API call

```
ApiInterfaceSR apiService =
            ApiClientSR.getXMLClient().create(ApiInterfaceSR.class);
    Call<PojoOddsResponse> call = apiService.getOddsData(API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<PojoOddsResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PojoOddsResponse> call, Response<PojoOddsResponse> response) {
            if (response.body() != null && response.code() == 200) {
                try {
                    String s = response.body().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+s);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("JSON exception", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PojoOddsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("api exception", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Help me, please.

Comment: *"Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"*. Is your response json or xml??

Comment: Try to remove `+"?"` and try again.

Comment: Then how to append API key to call

Comment: My response was XML

Hi @RoShan, I tried as you say, but the same issue
@GET("odds-" + oddsAccessMode + "1")
    Call<PojoOddsResponse> getOddsData(@Query("api_key") String api_key);